# How to insert values into a matrix and array declared in a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, matrix

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char **nameMonth;
    int *identifiers;
    float *temperature;
} ValuesMonth;
```

Inside my source code i get the information from a file **temperatures.txt**, the identifier, the name of the month and the temperature, as `int`, `char*` and `float` respectively:

The problem is that the only thing that inserts correcty is the id (`ValuesMonth.identifiers[i]=id;`), the others dont get inserted. I don't why, i'm programming on linux and the only error i get after executing the program is:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Do you have any idea how to insert it correctly?

```
#define MAX_BUFF 200

int main()
{
  FILE* file =fopen("temperatures.txt", "r+");
  char buff[MAX_BUFF];
  int id;
  float temp;

  ValuesMonth vectMonth;      

  int i;
  for (i =0; i<10; i++)
  {
     if(fscanf(file, "%d %s %f", &id, buff, &temp) != EOF)
     {
       vectMonth.identifiers[i]=id; 
       strcpy(vectMonth.nameMonth[i], buff);
       vectMonth.temperature[i]=temp;
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for *any* of the pointers in your `struct`. So you are writing into random invalid memory locations. First allocate memory for those pointers using `malloc` and then use it. After its use, `free` the allocated memory. Or just use `typedef struct {
    char nameMonth[10][MAX_BUFF];
    int identifiers[10];
    float temperature[10];
} ValuesMonth;`

Comment: I would definitely add better return value checking for `scanf`, in case of parse error. If `scanf` returns 0, 1 or 2 (instead of 3 for all conversions being successful), then your code does funny, possibly catastrophic things with stale or uninitialized variables.

Comment: @CoolGuy thaanks it worked!!

Comment: You should learn about dynamic memory allocation. Just add `vectMonth.identifiers = malloc(10 * sizeof *vectMonth.identifiers); vectMonth.temperature = malloc(10 * sizeof *vectMonth.temperature); vectMonth.nameMonth = malloc(10 * sizeof *vectMonth.nameMonth);` just before the loop and `vectMonth.nameMonth[i] = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);` just before the `if`. After the use of these, `free` the allocated memory using loops. It is better to check the return value of `malloc` to see if it was successful in allocating memory. Also, consider doing what @hyde said.